# How to use || and && together in one if statement

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if the `firstday` is equal to five or 6, in both cases if `totalDays` is equal to 31 then do something, for that purpose which statement is correct?

**Code 1:**

```
if (firstday > 5 || firstday > 6 && totalDays == 31){}
```

**Code 2:**

```
if (firstday > 5 && totalDays == 31 || firstday > 6 && totalDays == 31) { }
```

Comment: i think you dont need `|| firstday > 6` in 1st statement

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: Try to iterate your conditions in english and use `()` to group conditions. In you statement *firstday has to equal to 5 or 6, but in both case, totalDays must be 31*. So solve first part: `firstday === 5 || firstday === 6`. your second condition is `totalDays===31`. But this has to happen in case of both, so this becomes, `(firstday === 5 || firstday === 6) && totalDays===31`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the correct answer:

```
if ((firstday == 5 || firstday == 6) && totalDays == 31){
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Just a pointer, you should use `===` instead of `==`

Answer (score 0):

Both are wrong 
you need to use **==** operator for it.

```
if ((firstday == 5 || firstday == 6) && totalDays == 31){}
```

Comment: You need parenthesis around the || operators

Comment: ya. I just edited it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((firstday == 5 || firstday == 6) && totalDays == 31){}
```

Here the expression inside the inner most parenthesis`(firstday == 5 || firstday == 6)` is executed first. Based on the value the remaining expression is evaluated, if the above expression return false the remaining expression is not evaluated since the `false&&(true||false)` anyways false.

Comment: Would you bother explaining your code a bit? Just dumping it in an answer is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

First condition:
It returns *True*, if `firstday` is 5 **OR** 6.. **AND** TotalDays is 31.

```
if ((firstday == 5 || firstday == 6) && totalDays == 31){ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both your logic work, but you mentioned in your question that  "if the first day is equal to five or 6", so I would suggest that you use '==' instead of '>'. The latter will accept any value above 5, which does not match what you want.

Either one of the following lines will achieve your desired outcome.

```
if (firstday == 5 || firstday == 6 && totaldays == 31) {}
```

OR

```
if (firstday == 5 && totalDays == 31 || firstday == 6 && totalDays == 31) { }
```